# ASP.NET MVC Remove Model Required Attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a model which all have a `[Required]` attribute.
I also have a dropdown with options. When choosing the diffrent options, only the relevent input fields will be showed.
But when all the other inputs are hidden, I also want their Required Attribute to be disabled somehow. I am trying jQuery for this.
Here is my Razor page

```
<div id="Types" class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Type" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Type" class="form-control">
                    <option>Select a Type</option>
                    <option value="Book">Book</option>
                    <option value="AudioBook">AudioBook</option>
                    <option value="ReferenceBook">Reference Book</option>
                    <option value="DVD">DVD</option>
                </select>
<div id="ThePages" class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Pages" class="control-label"></label>
                <input id="ThePages" asp-for="Pages" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Pages" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="TheRunTime" class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RunTimeMinutes" class="control-label"></label>
                <input id="TheRunTime" asp-for="RunTimeMinutes" class="form-control">
                <span asp-validation-for="RunTimeMinutes" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="Borrowable" class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input id="Borrowable" class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsBorrowable" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsBorrowable)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div id="BorrowedBy" class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Borrower" class="control-label"></label>
                <input id="BorrowedBy" asp-for="Borrower" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Borrower" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="TheDate" class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Date" class="control-label"></label>
                <input id="TheDate" asp-for="Date" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Here is the jQuery Code

```
function hideOnLoad() {
        $("#ThePages").hide();
        $("#TheRunTime").hide();
        $("#Borrowable").hide();
        $("#BorrowedBy").hide();
        $("#TheDate").hide();
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        hideOnLoad();
        $("#Types select").change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == "Book") {
                $("#ThePages").show();
                $("#TheRunTime").hide().removeAttr();
                $("#Borrowable").show();
                $("#BorrowedBy").show();
                $("#TheDate").show();
            }
            else if (value == "AudioBook") {
                $("#ThePages").hide().removeAttr();
                $("#TheRunTime").show();
                $("#Borrowable").show();
                $("#BorrowedBy").show();
                $("#TheDate").show();
            }
            else if (value == "ReferenceBook") {
                $("#ThePages").show();
                $("#TheRunTime").hide().removeAttr();
                $("#Borrowable").hide().removeAttr();
                $("#BorrowedBy").hide().removeAttr();
                $("#TheDate").hide().removeAttr();
            }
            else if (value == "DVD") {
                $("#ThePages").hide().removeAttr();
                $("#TheRunTime").show();
                $("#Borrowable").show();
                $("#BorrowedBy").show();
                $("#TheDate").show();
            }
            else {
                hideOnLoad();
            }
        });
    });
```

So I want all the hidden elements to have their attribute removed.
What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,you cannot remove `[Required]` of the model,but you can try client side validation.
Here is a demo:
Model:

```
public class Model4
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Pages { get; set; }
    public string RunTimeMinutes { get; set; }
    public bool IsBorrowable { get; set; }
    public string Borrower { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }


}
```

View(`Id` is unique,so I remove the Ids of inputs):

```
<form method="post">
    <div id="Types" class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Type" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="Type" class="form-control">
            <option>Select a Type</option>
            <option value="Book">Book</option>
            <option value="AudioBook">AudioBook</option>
            <option value="ReferenceBook">Reference Book</option>
            <option value="DVD">DVD</option>
        </select>
        <div id="ThePages" class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Pages" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Pages" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Pages" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="TheRunTime" class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="RunTimeMinutes" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="RunTimeMinutes" class="form-control">
            <span asp-validation-for="RunTimeMinutes" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="Borrowable" class="form-group form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsBorrowable" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsBorrowable)
            </label>
        </div>
        <div id="BorrowedBy" class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Borrower" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Borrower" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Borrower" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="TheDate" class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Date" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Date" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

js((`IsBorrowable` is bool type,so I don't add `required` to it)):

```
function hideOnLoad() {
        $("#ThePages").hide();
        $("#TheRunTime").hide();
        $("#Borrowable").hide();
        $("#BorrowedBy").hide();
        $("#TheDate").hide();
    }
    function addRequired() {
        $("#Pages").attr("required", "required");
        $("#RunTimeMinutes").attr("required", "required");
        $("#Borrower").attr("required", "required");
        $("#Date").attr("required", "required");

    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        hideOnLoad();
        $("#Types select").change(function () {
            addRequired();
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == "Book") {
                $("#ThePages").show();
                $("#TheRunTime").hide().removeAttr();
                $("#RunTimeMinutes").removeAttr("required");
                $("#Borrowable").show();
                $("#BorrowedBy").show();
                $("#TheDate").show();
            }
            else if (value == "AudioBook") {
                $("#ThePages").hide().removeAttr();
                $("#Pages").removeAttr("required");
                $("#TheRunTime").show();
                $("#Borrowable").show();
                $("#BorrowedBy").show();
                $("#TheDate").show();
            }
            else if (value == "ReferenceBook") {
                $("#ThePages").show();
                $("#TheRunTime").hide().removeAttr();
                $("#Borrowable").hide().removeAttr();
                $("#BorrowedBy").hide().removeAttr();
                $("#TheDate").hide().removeAttr();
                $("#RunTimeMinutes").removeAttr("required");
                $("#Borrower").removeAttr("required");
                $("#Date").removeAttr("required");
            }
            else if (value == "DVD") {
                $("#ThePages").hide().removeAttr();
                $("#Pages").removeAttr("required");
                $("#TheRunTime").show();
                $("#Borrowable").show();
                $("#BorrowedBy").show();
                $("#TheDate").show();
            }
            else {
                hideOnLoad();
                $("#Pages").removeAttr("required");
                $("#RunTimeMinutes").removeAttr("required");
                $("#Borrower").removeAttr("required");
                $("#Date").removeAttr("required");
            }
        });
    });
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for a well written answer! This approach works :)